# How do I find the position of a character in a SQLite column?

Tags: sql, sqlite

If the result "`joe@stackoverflow.com`" and I want to find the position of the `@` symbol (3). Is it possible?  It does not appear that SQLite has the equivalent of `INSTR`, `LOCATE`, `POSITION` or any such function.

```
SELECT ?('joe@stackoverflow.com')
```

**Update** I ended up registering a custom extension function, but was surprised that I had to.

Comment: Could you please share your solution

Answer (score 15):

Don't know whether this is a recent addition, but the [`INSTR` function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr) will indeed find the 1st instance.

Comment: Added in 3.7.15 which was released after the question was posted. http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_7_15

Comment: Agreed: nonetheless, this is currently the correct answer for people who've Googled in , isn't it?

Comment: yes, it is. as was for me that arrived here by search

Answer (score 12):

Retrieve filename from a path:

```
select replace(path, rtrim(path, replace(path, '/', '' ) ), '') from example;
```

Got from http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/38836-sqlite-question-how-do-i-find-the-position-of-a-character-in-a-string?page=2, hope it could help someone.

Comment: This is a neat trick how to do it without `instr` function added in version 3.7.15.

Comment: Smart alternative way

Answer (score 3):

SELECT instr(COLUMN, '@') FROM TABLE

Comment: I would suggest you to provide more support for your answer. For example, share the source (https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-functions/sqlite-instr/) or briefly explain what the INSTR() function does. You could evnetually compare it with other possible approaches.

Comment: The actual shores should be something like https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr

Answer (score 2):

Got this from [a spiceworks posting](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/38836-sqlite-question-how-do-i-find-the-position-of-a-character-in-a-string?page=2):

> The first step is to remove all characters up to a specific character
>   using ltrim or rtrim. If you're retrieving a filename then you trim
>   all characters that are not slashes. If you're retrieving a username
>   then you trim everything that is not an @ character. You can then use
>   that trimmed string in a replace function to replace its occurrence
>   with an empty string. That will provide you with every character that
>   you just trimmed in the first step. In other words, the username or
>   filename.

```
create table example (path varchar(256), email varchar(128));

insert into example values ('/path/to/file1.txt', 'user@domain.com');
```

> **Retrieve user from email:**

```
select replace(email, ltrim(email, '1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM!#$%^&*()_+-=`~[]\/{}|;:,.<>?'),'') from example;
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see [here](http://www.sqlite.org/contrib), charindex is not in SQLite standard package(At least in 3.6.2 version that i use). But [this](http://www.sqlite.org/contrib) extension (extension-functions.c) has Charindex, which is basically the same as the VB instr.

To add these functions to sqlite:

We have to compile the C source code to make the sqlite extension (Assuming you are on Windows):

- Install the [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/category/wiki/download) compiler, small and easy to do.
- copy sqlite3.h to the same folder
- gcc -fPIC -lm -shared extension-functions.c -o libsqlitefunctions.dll
- fireup sqlite
- select load_extension('libsqlitefunctions.dll')

There are other string and math functions as well.

Comment: I've had also to copy sqlite3ext.h to the folder I was compiling the [extension-functions.c] (http://www.sqlite.org/contrib/download/extension-functions.c?get=25)
Compiled successfully with gcc-4.8.3 from cygwin x64 installation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `charindex('c', column, 0)`

it depends on the version of SQLite.

Comment: This is sql server function, not sqlite

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Python, but this can be done using the command line tools.

This solution uses Regex to extract a date:

```
import re
import sqlite3

def get_date_from_path(item: str, expr: str):
    return re.search(pattern=expr, string=item).group()

conn = sqlite3.connect(database=r'Name.db')
conn.create_function("GET_DATE_FROM_PATH", 2, get_date_from_path)

SELECT GET_DATE_FROM_PATH('C:\reports\report_20190731.csv', r'[0-9]{8}');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
   email,
   POSITION('@' IN email)
From
   table
```

Here's a basic resource you might like: http://sqlzoo.net/howto/source/z.dir/tip238311/sqlite

Comment: Hi kuru, kuru.  I ended up building a custom extension, but POSITION is not available on my build of SQLite.  Does it work on yours?

Comment: Likely SQL syntax error: SELECT email, POSITION('[' IN email) FROM table [ near "table": syntax error ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE

Comment: I'm not big into sqllite, but I'd guess that the square bracket might be giving you trouble because (I think) sqllite treats those as special characters.  Try double quotes around that instead of single quotes -- maybe that will do it.

Answer (score -8):

Position of char '@' can be finded by function CHARINDEX (MSSQL):

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('@', 'joe@stackoverflow.com', 0)
```

Comment: I wish people would read the question before answering, CHARINDEX is not implemented in SQLITE !!