# sqlalchemy @hybrid_property expressions for folder and filename from filepath. Very easy to write in pure python

Tags: python, database, sqlite, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a database I'm using sqlalchemy with, which involves storing the locations of files.

I have something like:

```
class FileLocation(ORMBase): 
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    filepath = Column('filepath', String)
```

and I want to add hybrid expressions of the folder and filename corresponding to each filepath. This is pretty easy to do with regular python strings, of course, but I can't find a way to do this sort of string manipulation in sqlalchemy expressions.

```
from sqlalchemy import func

class FileLocation(ORMBase):

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    filepath = Column('filepath', String)


    @hybrid_property
    def folder(self):
        return os.path.dirname(self.filepath)

    @folder.expression
    def folder(cls):
        # How to  get folder for sql queries???
        last_pathsep_index = # ???
        return func.substr(cls.filepath, 0, last_pathsep_index)

    @hybrid_property
    def filename(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.filepath)

    @filename.expression
    def filename(cls):
        # How to  get filename for sql queries???
        last_pathsep_index = # ???
        return func.substr(cls.filepath, last_pathsep_index+1, func.len(cls.filepath))
```

How would I go about writing the `@filename.expression` and `@folder.expression` attributes, which currently are shown with incomplete implementations?

Comment: This is really just an SQL question at this point - you just need to write functions in your SQL dialect that extract the desired portions of the string, then translate them to sqlalchemy using func. You'll probably have more luck getting a useful answer if you simplify your question to remove the sqlalchemy references. Since you tagged this sqlite, perhaps this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989895/how-do-i-find-the-position-of-a-character-in-a-sqlite-column

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis, I ended up finding a solution through your link. Thank you!

Comment: Since you're using SQLite, you could create UDFs that call the same Python functions: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.create_function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I ended up with, which I found through @AnthonyCarapetis' suggested link.

This ended up being more just a straight SQL (SQLite) question than about sqlalchemy, but I'll leave the sqlalchemy code here in case it helps anyone else.

```
import os

import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import case, func

def getpathsep(osname=os.name):
    """use os.name to determine osname"""
    return case([(osname == 'nt', '\\')], else_='/')


def dirname(filepath, osname=os.name):
    """use os.name to determine osname"""
    pathsep = getpathsep(osname)
    replaced = func.replace(filepath, pathsep, '')
    filename = func.rtrim(filepath, replaced)
    return func.substr(filepath, 0, func.length(filename))


def pathsplit(filepath, osname=os.name):
    """use os.name to determine osname"""
    folder = dirname(filepath, osname)
    l = func.length(folder) + 1  # add 1 for (back) slash char
    basename = func.substr(filepath, l + 1)  # First index is 1
    return folder, basename


def basename(filepath, osname=os.name):
    """use os.name to determine osname"""
    return pathsplit(filepath, osname)[1]


class FileLocation(ORMBase):

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    osname = Column('osname', String)
    filepath = Column('filepath', String)


    @hybrid_property
    def folder(self):
        return os.path.dirname(self.filepath)

    @folder.expression
    def folder(cls):
        return dirname(cls.filepath, cls.osname)

    @hybrid_property
    def filename(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.filepath)

    @filename.expression
    def filename(cls):
        return basename(cls.filepath, cls.osname)
```